# Whats wrong with my loop?

Tags: java, loops

Im currently trying to read a file and store them accordingly. I've read the from the textfile and store them into an arraylist and now I'm just trying to store the framnumbers but i keep getting the same framenumber when I print out the contents of the arrayList.

contents of my textfile

```
FrameNumber: 49136
FrameNumber: 49137
FrameNumber: 49138
FrameNumber: 49139
FrameNumber: 49140
FrameNumber: 49141
288
200
3848
287
191
3859
283
145
3849
```

my readfile function

```
public void readFile() 
{
    ArrayList<Frame> frameList = new ArrayList<Frame>();
    ArrayList<Joint> jointList = new ArrayList<Joint>();
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Frame retrievedFrame = new Frame();
    Joint tempJoint = new Joint();
    Coordinate tempCoordinate = new Coordinate();

    try
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"UTF-8"));
        BOMSkipper.skip(bufferedReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();            

        while (line != null)
        {
            al.add(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        bufferedReader.close();        
    }          
    catch (IOException e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
    {
        if (al.get(i).contains("FrameNumber:") == true)
        {
            temp = al.get(i).replace("FrameNumber: ", "");
            temp = temp.trim();                    
            retrievedFrame.setFrameNumber(Integer.parseInt(temp));
            frameList.add(retrievedFrame);
            System.out.println("Frame Detected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Frame");
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < frameList.size(); j++)
    {
        System.out.println(frameList.size());
        System.out.println("Frame Number: " + frameList.get(j).getFrameNumber());            
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only creating a single `Frame`. You create the `Frame` with `Frame retrievedFrame = new Frame();` and then for each line you change the frame number of that frame and add it to the list again.

What you probably want is to create a new `Frame` each time:

```
if (al.get(i).contains("FrameNumber:")) {
    temp = al.get(i).replace("FrameNumber: ", "");
    temp = temp.trim();                    
    Frame retrievedFrame = new Frame();
    retrievedFrame.setFrameNumber(Integer.parseInt(temp));
    frameList.add(retrievedFrame);
    System.out.println("Frame Detected");
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see. I thought it will just replace the current values with the new values. Thanks